# Deleting form values with same name attribute

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

i have a problem, i want to delete some name and leave some. but the problem when i try to delete one name it deletes the first one yet you have clicked to delete the last one.

so the main point is

how can i delete or send the name value which i want to delete instead deleting the first one or all.

because they all have same name 'info' but different values.
so i want to be deleting some and leave some instead all or only on top ones

any idea how i can do this

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#remove").click(function(event) {
    Execute();
  });

  function Execute() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'remove.php',
      data: {
        'info': $("input[name='info']").val()
      },
      success: function(response) {},
      error: function() {
        alert("error");
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="info" value="John">
  <button type='button' id='remove'> delete</button>

  <input type="text" name="info" value="Jane">
  <button type='button' id='remove'> delete</button>

  <input type="text" name="info" value="jacobo">
  <button type='button' id='remove'> delete</button>
</form>
```

Comment: The name should be unique for each field.

Comment: then what about this part if the name is unique data: {
        'info': $("input[name='info']").val()
      },

Comment: because am sending the name tag value through ajax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First, use a `class` instead of an `id` for your buttons. The ID should be unique.
2. Second, you can grab the previous input for the clicked button (target).

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.remove').click(function(event) {
    execute($(event.target).prev('input'));
  });

  function execute($input) {
    console.log(`Deleting: ${$input.val()}`);
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'remove.php',
      data: {
        'info': $input.val()
      },
      success: function(response) {},
      error: function() {
        alert("error");
      }
    });
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="info" value="John">
  <button type="button" class="remove">Delete</button>

  <input type="text" name="info" value="Jane">
  <button type="button" class="remove">Delete</button>

  <input type="text" name="info" value="jacobo">
  <button type="button" class="remove">Delete</button>
</form>
```